# How to print cell "values" in MsgBox?

Tags: excel, vba

I have VBA code that goes to a reference workbook and makes a report based on sheet names needed.
After this I output into cells all the sheets it couldn't find. I want to put it in a MsgBox.

Output of those missing sheets:

```vb
On Error Resume Next
Do While y \<= x
    Workbooks(maker).Activate
    Z = Range("u10:u" & cnt).Find(what:=y, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Select
    If Err \> 0 Then
        V = Range("E10:E" & cnt).Find(what:=y, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Select
        t = Selection.Offset(0, 1)
        'This is where the not found worksheets are printed in column w
        Range("w" & q).Value = t
        q = q + 1
        y = y + 1
    Else
        t = Selection.Offset(0, -1)
        Workbooks(Filename).Sheets(t).Copy After:=Workbooks(temp).Sheets(Workbooks(temp).Sheets.Count)
        Workbooks(maker).Activate
        y = y + 1
    End If
Loop
On Error GoTo 0
```

How would I make that `Range("w" &q).Value = t` into a message box that lists the worksheet names?

Comment: `MsgBox t` or `MsgBox Range("w" &q).Value`?

Comment: `MsgBox Join(Application.Transpose(Range("W1:W" & q - 1)), vbLf)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, What line pops the error message?

Either way, this is a way to build a message from multiple lines. I realize you're finding sheets that don't exist, so the whole `For Each WS` thing doesn't apply... but it's useful to demonstrate.

```
Sub MessageFromCellValues()

    Dim Msg As String
    Dim maker As String
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim X As Long
    Dim Y As Long
    
    maker = "Your Worksheet Name.xlsm"
    
    'Do While Y <= X
        
        ' ... Your Code
        
    'Loop
    
    Msg = " This is the list of Sheet Names " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    
    For Each WS In Workbooks(maker).Worksheets
        Msg = Msg & " - " & WS.Name & vbCrLf
    Next WS '
    
    MsgBox Msg, vbOKOnly, "Sheets List"
    
End Sub
```

Example:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
On Error Resume Next
    sMsgTxt = "" ' Initialize msgbox string
Do While y <= x
Workbooks(maker).Activate
Z = Range("u10:u" & cnt).Find(what:=y, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Select
If Err > 0 Then
V = Range("E10:E" & cnt).Find(what:=y, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Select
t = Selection.Offset(0, 1)
'This is where the not found worksheets are printed in column w
Range("w" & q).Value = t
    sMsgTxt = sMsgTxt & t & vbCrLf ' Append to msgbox string
q = q + 1
y = y + 1
Else
t = Selection.Offset(0, -1)
Workbooks(Filename).Sheets(t).Copy After:=Workbooks(temp).Sheets(Workbooks(temp).Sheets.Count)
Workbooks(maker).Activate
y = y + 1
End If
Loop
    MsgBox sMsgTxt ' Output msgbox string
On Error GoTo 0
```